# PHP - detect text direction (ltr/rtl) from UA string or external service, is it possible?

Tags: php, text, detect, right-to-left

I would like to detect not only the client language (which I already do using a combination of different methods, from UA string extraction to geolocation services) but I would also like to detect the text direction in an automatic fashion, if possible.

I know there aren't too many languages using right-to-left direction (not as many as left-to-right ones, at least), so a possible solution would be to do something like `$rtl = ['ar', 'he', ..., '<whatever>']; if (in_array(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2), $rtl)) { $direction = "rtl"; } else { $direction = "ltr"; }` but looks to me like there's (probably) a better solution.

I'm still studying some of the language recognition API's out there like LangID, AlchemyAPI and DetectLanguage, but they seem to do the same: recognize the text language, but not the text direction.

Any recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information about the direction of a language is accessible through the ICU library.

Using the [cosmopolitan](https://github.com/salarmehr/cosmopolitan) package it could be as simple as below.

```
<?php
require __DIR__. "/vendor/autoload.php";
use Salarmehr\Cosmopolitan\Cosmo;

echo Cosmo::create('fa')->direction(); // rlt
echo Cosmo::create('en')->direction(); // ltr
```

Comment: You're right. Seems I already took the best approach (or, at least, an efficient-enough one) so I'm sticking to it. Any other approach would have probably overcomplicated it. Thanks :)

Comment: @JulioMaríaMecaHansen please see my updated answer.